# Binary Tree using Scala

Tags: scala, binary-tree

```
class MyBst {
  def createTree(list:List[Int]): Node={
    require(list.nonEmpty)
      val nodes = list.map(element => Node(None, element, None))
      val root = nodes.head
      def create(node:List[Node], tree:Node):Node=
        nodes match{
          case head::tail => create(tail,insert(tree,head))
          case Nil => tree
        }
      create(nodes.tail,root)
  }
  def insert(tree:Node,elem:Node):Node = {
    if(tree.data >= elem.data)
      if(tree.left.isDefined)
        tree.copy(left = Some(insert(tree.left.get,elem)))
       else
        tree.copy(left = Some(elem))
    else
      if(tree.right.isDefined)
        tree.copy(right = Some(insert(tree.right.get,elem)))
      else
        tree.copy(right=Some(elem))
  }

}
case class Node(left:Option[Node], data:Int, right:Option[Node])
```

I m trying to create a tree using scala. But this is not working. It is showing Stack Over Flow Error.

> [info]   java.lang.StackOverflowError:
>
> [info]   at binarySearchTree.MyBst.insert(MyBst.scala:21)
>
> [info]   at binarySearchTree.MyBst.insert(MyBst.scala:21)
>
> [info]   at binarySearchTree.MyBst.insert(MyBst.scala:21)
>
> [info]   at binarySearchTree.MyBst.insert(MyBst.scala:21)
>
> [info]   at binarySearchTree.MyBst.insert(MyBst.scala:21)
>
> [info]   at binarySearchTree.MyBst.insert(MyBst.scala:21)
>
> [info]   at binarySearchTree.MyBst.insert(MyBst.scala:21)
>
> [info]   at binarySearchTree.MyBst.insert(MyBst.scala:21)
>
> [info]   at binarySearchTree.MyBst.insert(MyBst.scala:21)
>
> [info]   at binarySearchTree.MyBst.insert(MyBst.scala:21)

Comment: I called createTree(list). and list has some values

Comment: Hint : A stack overflow indicates the call stack has grown too big and exceeded available memory. This is most probably due to a mistake in your recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `create` function, you are pattern matching on `nodes` instead of `node`. As soon as you fix that, you are probably going to realize that create Tree doesn't return the top of the tree